# Почему не срабатывает -=1

Tags: python, python-3.x, for, range

Такой вопрос: почему не срабатывает -=1 в коде:

```
dx = 3
dy = 3 ** 2
m = [[1 for x in range(dx)] for y in range(dy)]

for i in range(dy):
    print("Текущее значение i =", i)
    for j in range(dx):
        m[i][j] = random.randint(1, 2)
    for d in range(i):
        if d != i and m[i] == m[d]:
            i -= 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На каждой итерации цикла, `range` будет возвращать следующее значение `i`, поэтому изменения `i` внутри цикла будут только до следующей итерации.

```
for i in range(3):
    print(i, end=' -> ')
    i -= 1

    print(i)
```

В консоли будет:

```
0 -> -1
1 -> 0
2 -> 1
```

---

Вам нужно использовать `while` вместе с счетчиком:

```
dy = 3 ** 2
i = 0

while i < dy:
    print("Текущее значение i =", i)

    i += 1
```

Консоль:

```
Текущее значение i = 0
Текущее значение i = 1
Текущее значение i = 2
Текущее значение i = 3
Текущее значение i = 4
Текущее значение i = 5
Текущее значение i = 6
Текущее значение i = 7
Текущее значение i = 8
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте заменить:

```py
for i in range(dy):
  #Ваш код
```

на:

```
i = 0
while i < dy:
  #Ваш код
  i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что `range` уже создан и с переменной `i` никак не связан.